# Eloquent's where/orWhere combination failing

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, where-clause

I have a solution to my problem yet it is bothering me and wish there was no need for a solution since problem makes no sense.

I have a table links; as if 2 users are linked. The table is a simple:
`id`, `user_1_id`, `user_2_id`, `status`, `created`...

I want both users to be able to delete in a simple controller destroy method:

Normally I write:

```php
Links::where(['user_1_id' => auth()->id(),'user_2_id' => $user->id])
    ->orWhere(['user_1_id' => $user->id, 'user_2_id' => auth()->id()])
    ->delete();
```

parsing the `$user` class through url...

my current solution includes to call the

```php
Links::where([...])->delete()
```

once and if it is equal 0, then call it again with the user's `id`s inverted; and it works...

The `orWhere` method just returns and deletes all of the links made... normally `user_2_id` is always the same and `user_1_id` varies from 99-108... Why might this be?

Comment: What is the exact issue? Doesn't the query work and give the desired result?

Comment: I might be wrong, but this sounds like an Eloquent relationship that you should be specifying in the User model. Everything is easier like that. You should probably [read more about Eloquent Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships) to see if any of the relationships work for your use case.

Comment: Nothing wrong with this query, it will result in `DELETE FROM links WHERE (user_1_id = ? AND user_2_id = ?) OR (user_1_id=? AND user_2_id=?) AND deleted_at IS NULL;` Perhaps your data is not what you expect.

Comment: @Donkarnash problem is: first query works fine and returns one item deleted; but when query one fails and move on to the next it does not return 1 deleted it returns all that belong to 'user_2_id' deleted;

Comment: As confirmed by @miken32 the generated SQL seems fine, don't see any problems with that.

Comment: yep it was just eloquent's syntax...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function scopeBetween($query, $sender, $recipient)
    {
        $query->where([
            ['sender_id', $sender->id],
            ['recipient_id', $recipient->id]
        ])->orWhere([
            ['sender_id', $recipient->id],
            ['recipient_id', $sender->id]
        ]);
    }
```

found out that this is the best solution... to create a scope function that takes for parameter the sender and recipient as to identify if a friendship has been created or not

Answer (score -1):

Guess you have syntax error in the query, try

```php
Links::where([
        ['user_1_id', auth()->id()],
        ['user_2_id', $user->id]
    ])
    ->orWhere([
        ['user_1_id', $user->id],
        ['user_2_id', auth()->id()]
    ])
    ->delete();
```

Comment: `where(['column1'=>'value1', 'column2'=>'value2'])` is fine syntax when you don't need to specify an operator. No error there.

Comment: @miken32 Didn't know about this either docs https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#simple-where-clauses don't suggest this syntax - Thanks for sharing - could you suggest any source where I can learn about such undocumented things or is it that studying the framework code in github repo is the only way to find out such hidden short syntax gems

Comment: Just stuff I've picked up after a few years working with Laravel. Probably a lot of them I learned by making mistakes and doing things the "wrong" way and it still worked!

Comment: Oh okay. Guess will have to start documenting on my local machine probably with `.md` files for future reference. :)

Comment: this is actually the answer! thnx

Comment: @EstuardoQuan If the answer helped you solve the issue in question pls remember to mark it as accepted/upvote for the benefit of subsequent visitors.